# Wrong histogram with built in hist() function

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, bar-chart

bootstrap.rand is a matrix with 253x10000 integer values ranging from 1 to 253.
The built-in hist() command returns:

```
hist(bootstrap.rand)
```

[image: Histogram with hist()]

When building a histogram by using the barplot command I get a complete different result:

```
bar(histc(bootstrap.rand(:),unique(bootstrap.rand)))
```

[image: Histogram by using bar()]

Because of the y-axis in the first picture obviously it does not do what i want. Why this difference?

Comment: ["To plot the histogram, use `bar(binranges,bincounts,'histc')`."](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html)

Comment: In the first, there is one histogram for each column, each with a different color, hence the "gradient" look. Try `his(bootstrap.rand(:,1:2))` to see what happens.

Comment: @excaza your comment helped for another way to do it.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut your comment helped for understanding what is going on in the hist() command.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html)?

Comment: @EBH You are totally right. I thought it was the only histogram command and did not know that there is a second one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `hist` and `histc` are [not recommended by MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

> hist is not recommended. Use histogram instead.
>
> For more information, including suggestions on updating code, see Replace Discouraged Instances of hist and histc.

Instead use [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) which gives the wanted output:

```
bootstrap = randi(253,253,10000);
histogram(bootstrap)
```

[image: histogram]

The shape of `bootstrap` doesn't matter, it will always be treated as `bootstrap(:)`.